Extract and Process Text from PDF Files
I know the basics of Python, JavaScript, CSS, HTML, and SQL. While trying to automate a job task, I’ve run into some problems. First of all, I want to be clear that I know nothing about VBA. This is my first time trying to use it, and most of the code was made with the help of AI.
The Task
I'm trying to create a macro that allows me to copy all the text from some PDF files, clean it, and organize the relevant information into rows and columns. This needs to be usable by anyone, even people who are not tech-savvy.
One big problem is that since I need this to run on a heavily restricted work laptop, the only thing I can use is Excel, not even the paid version of Acrobat.
This macro should do the following:
Prompt the user to select a folder.
One by one, open the PDFs and copy the content.
Paste the content into a Notepad.
Copy the content from the Notepad.
Filter the information.
Line by line, organize the information into columns and rows.
By trial and error, I got this:
Sub EXTRACT_DATA()
Dim myPath As String
Dim myfile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim ExR As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim AllText As String
Dim Paragraphs As Variant
Dim Paragraph As Variant ' Changed to Variant
Dim CleanedParagraph As String
Dim DatePart As String
Dim ColB As String
Dim ColC As String
Dim ColD As String
Dim ColE As String
Dim FolderPicker As FileDialog

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    On Error GoTo ResetSettings
    
    ' Open folder picker dialog
    Set FolderPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With FolderPicker
        .Title = "Select Folder Containing PDF Files"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then
            MsgBox "No folder selected. Exiting.", vbExclamation
            GoTo ResetSettings
        End If
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With
    
    myExtension = "*.pdf"
    myfile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)
    
    If myfile = "" Then
        MsgBox "No PDF files found in the selected folder. Exiting.", vbExclamation
        GoTo ResetSettings
    End If
    
    i = 0 ' Initialize row counter
    
    ' Set starting point on Sheet RAW, Cell A2
    Set ExR = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RAW").Range("A2")
    
    Do While myfile <> ""
        ' Convert PDF to text using Notepad
        Shell "notepad.exe " & myPath & myfile, vbNormalFocus
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03") ' Wait for Notepad to open
    
        ' Copy text from Notepad to clipboard
        AppActivate "Notepad"
        SendKeys "^a", True ' Select all text
        SendKeys "^c", True ' Copy selected text
        SendKeys "%{F4}", True ' Close Notepad
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02") ' Wait for clipboard to update
    
        ' Retrieve text from clipboard
        AllText = GetClipboardText()
    
        If AllText = "" Then
            MsgBox "Failed to retrieve text from clipboard for file: " & myfile, vbExclamation
            GoTo NextFile
        End If
    
        ' Process each line from Notepad
        Paragraphs = Split(AllText, vbCrLf)
        x = 0 ' Reset row offset
    
        For Each Paragraph In Paragraphs
            ' Ignore lines with specific strings
            If ContainsAny(CStr(Paragraph), Array( **LIST OF EXCLUDED WORDS, ERASED TO GIVE AWAY SENSITIVE INFORMATION** )) Then
                GoTo SkipLine
            End If
    
            ' Trim leading and trailing spaces, parentheses, and apostrophes
            Paragraph = Trim(Replace(Replace(Replace(Paragraph, "(", ""), ")", ""), "'", ""))
    
            ' Remove extra spaces between words
            CleanedParagraph = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(Paragraph)
    
            ' Check if the line ends with a word with 3 or more characters
            Dim lastSpace As Integer
            lastSpace = InStrRev(CleanedParagraph, " ")
            If lastSpace > 0 Then
                Dim lastWord As String
                lastWord = Trim(Right(CleanedParagraph, Len(CleanedParagraph) - lastSpace))
    
                ' Ignore lines where the last word has 3 or fewer characters
                If Len(lastWord) > 3 Then
                    ' Check if the line starts with a date (assuming mm/dd/yy format)
                    If IsDate(Left(CleanedParagraph, 8)) Then
                        DatePart = Left(CleanedParagraph, 8) ' Column A: Date
    
                        ' Find the first non-blank character after the date
                        Dim startIndex As Integer
                        startIndex = 9
                        While Mid(CleanedParagraph, startIndex, 1) = " " And startIndex <= Len(CleanedParagraph)
                            startIndex = startIndex + 1
                        Wend
    
                        ' Column B: 12 characters after the date (or as many as available)
                        ColB = Mid(CleanedParagraph, startIndex, 12)
    
                        ' Find the position of the last space
                        lastSpace = InStrRev(CleanedParagraph, " ")
    
                        ' Column E: Last word on the line
                        ColE = Right(CleanedParagraph, Len(CleanedParagraph) - lastSpace)
    
                        ' Find the first space after Column B to determine the start of Column C
                        Dim firstSpaceAfterB As Integer
                        firstSpaceAfterB = InStr(startIndex + 12, CleanedParagraph, " ")
    
                        ' Column C: First word after Column B
                        ColC = Mid(CleanedParagraph, firstSpaceAfterB + 1, InStr(firstSpaceAfterB + 1, CleanedParagraph, " ") - firstSpaceAfterB - 1)
    
                        ' Column D: Remaining words excluding any word containing numbers and stopping at the first word containing numbers
                        ColD = ""
                        Dim words() As String
                        Dim word As Variant
                        words = Split(Mid(CleanedParagraph, firstSpaceAfterB + Len(ColC) + 1, lastSpace - firstSpaceAfterB - Len(ColC)), " ")
                        For Each word In words
                            If word Like "*[0-9]*" Then
                                Exit For
                            Else
                                ColD = ColD & word & " "
                            End If
                        Next word
                        ColD = Trim(ColD)
    
                        ' Output to Excel columns
                        ExR.Offset(x, 0).Value = DatePart
                        ExR.Offset(x, 1).Value = ColB
                        ExR.Offset(x, 2).Value = ColC
                        ExR.Offset(x, 3).Value = ColD
                        ExR.Offset(x, 4).Value = ColE
    
                        x = x + 1 ' Move to next row in Excel
                    End If
                End If
            End If

SkipLine:
Next Paragraph

        i = i + x ' Update row counter

NextFile:
myfile = Dir ' Get next file
DoEvents ' Ensure it opens
Loop

    ' Clean up
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    Exit Sub

ResetSettings:
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "An error occurred: " & Err.Description, vbExclamation
    Resume Next

End Sub

Function GetClipboardText() As String
Dim ClipboardData As MSForms.DataObject
Set ClipboardData = New MSForms.DataObject

    On Error Resume Next
    ClipboardData.GetFromClipboard
    GetClipboardText = ClipboardData.GetText(1)

End Function`

Function ContainsAny(text As String, substrings As Variant) As Boolean
Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(substrings) To UBound(substrings)
If InStr(1, text, substrings(i), vbTextCompare) \> 0 Then
ContainsAny = True
Exit Function
End If
Next i
ContainsAny = False
End Function

So far, this code worked! a few times, and now for some reason is not working anymore, I’m still trying to make it work but any guidance will help me to fix it.
I know excel has a get data from pdf function but even using filters this leads to some issues from the users end,
I already tried
coping directly from the pdf file: it doesn’t do it properly when the pdf goes from one page to another it puts together the last and first lines on the pages and they cannot be filtered properly, i only have the free version of adobe to work with, I can’t install any other software.
using word insted of notepad: doesn’t fix the problem from extracting directly from the pdf.
at the moment when I try to use the macro excel gets stuck and stops responding but the same code worked perfectly a week ago when I test it multiple times

Without a sample of the type of PDF you're working with it's going to be difficult to offer good suggestions here.  I opened a couple of PDF's in Notepad and neither of them had any useable content.  If it worked for you previously then there's something specific to your files which allowed that.

We use the PdfToText command line utility from XpdfReader. It is free to use, fast, and requires no install.

You cannot expect to open a PDF using MS NotePad and get any usable text. As most will be encoded as per the notepad view on the left. At best there may be some plain non encoded text, however that is not normally usable either.
The windows PDF Viewer is MS Edge and you can copy and paste from that to NotePad, Word or Excel.

Generally that is no use either, as line relationships are not the same in PDF as document formats. So the characters become at best side by side.
Adobe Acrobat Reader has a "Save as Text" for accessibility, however that will not work with graphical objects, such as text that is non conventional.

The only "sometimes useful" MS Office PDF import is MS Word where the relationships and formatting e.g. lines or styles may be retained during conversion.

Answer
Use Word.exe not Notepad.exe to open the PDF.
